# Simpliest way how to hide button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have this code (button):

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <button type="button" onclick="self.close()"
     style="background:url('/url/to/image') no-repeat left top; height:48px; width:412px; border: none;">
  </button>
</a>
```

and I would like to hide this button after click. What is the simpliest way how to do it?

Comment: is there a reason for putting the button inside an <a> tag?

Comment: Hey, can you explain what do you me by "simpliest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest? That's a matter of opinion I suppose,  you could just call jquery's `hide()`?

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <button type="button" onclick="$(this).hide(); return false;"
 style="background:url('/url/to/image') no-repeat left top; height:48px; width:412px; border: none;">
  </button>
</a>
```

You've wrapped it in an anchor tag so you should prevent default behaviour if you want to stop that from redirecting to `https://www.google.com/`

Answer (score 2):

My way to go would be as such:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

Still not sure about what *"simplest"* means. To me, it is the above code: I avoid writing Javascript in the middle of the DOM, within the HTML tags. Wrapping them in `<script>` tags all in one place (generally right before `</body>`) is more conveniant.

But this is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="this.style.display='none';" style="height:1em;"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The word *Simplest* could have several shapes of solution. In my opinion the `display:none` is probably the faster solving as runtime.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:this.style.display='none'"
     style="background:url('/url/to/image') no-repeat left top; height:48px; width:412px; border: none;">
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using `addEventListener` to listen for a click event on the button. Your callback function will hide the element:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => e.target.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<button type="button">Click to hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers. The simpliest solutions for me were that from Giulio Bambini, Sean T and MyGeertRo :)